# When using this code, I get a syntax error in the Windows console

Tags: rust, subprocess, rust-cargo

There is a code that executes a command in the Windows terminal. But when using it, I get a syntax error from the Windows terminal

```
use subprocess::{Exec};

fn main() {
    let cmd = "rd /s /q \"%ProgramData%\\NVIDIA Corporation\\umdlogs\"";
    let out = Exec::shell(cmd).join();

    println!("{out:#?}");
}
```

I've been sitting for the whole day, I can't figure out what the mistake is. I want to make a simple utility to clean temporary files

I get this error. As far as I understand the problem is in escaping characters, most likely they are transmitted incorrectly
A syntax error in the file name, folder name, or volume label.

```
Ok(
 Exited(
 123,
 ),
)
```

Comment: Start by using raw strings (`r"..."`) as that will help with the backslashes.

Comment: Mind to share *what* error you get?

Comment: And also show the errors you are getting.

Comment: I get this error. As far as I understand the problem is in escaping characters, most likely they are transmitted incorrectly

Ok(
 Exited(
 123,
 ),
)

Comment: I would first check that `%ProgramData%` get's expanded by `Exec::shell()`.  If not you need to look it up yourself and add it manually in the command line.

Comment: I checked, %ProgramData% works in Exec::shell()

Comment: You have a string there. You could check in a debugger what it contains to see if it the expected. Or at the least print it.

Comment: if I print cmd, then I get the desired result. If you enter it into the Windows terminal, everything works correctly. But when you try to enter through this code, a syntax error occurs

Comment: Have you tried `cmd` and `args` instead of `shell`?